# Look for least frequent digit in an integer C++

Tags: c++, arrays, element

I have to say first there's one rule to my problem  - Can't use anything other than functions, loops, arrays.

Here's what i have currently:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int getLeastOccurredDigit(int);

int main()
{
    int uIn;
    cout << "Enter an Integer: ";
    cin >> uIn;
    cout << "\nThe least occurred digit in " << uIn << " is " << getLeastOccurredDigit(uIn) << endl;
    return 0;
}

int getLeastOccurredDigit(int number)
{
    int freqList[10] = { 0 };
    int pNum = (number < 0) ? -number : number;
    while (pNum != 0)
    {
        freqList[(pNum % 10)]++;
        pNum /= 10;
    }
}
```

I basically keep counts of all possible appearance of digits(0-9) in the array:

```
freqList[]
```

The next step is to of course compare all element in the array; ignoring 0s, and output the number that appeared the least.

I have no idea what i could do to loop through the array, compare the elements while ignoring 0s, and come out with the smallest value.

Comment: Use another `for()` loop after your `while()` loop and check the values to extract the smallest one?

Comment: Skip the `0` values additionally to ignore and that's it, yes. You also want to have a `max` value determined in your while loop to start with.

Comment: `for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
 {
  if(freqList[i] < min)
  {
   min = freqList[i];
  }`

something like this?

Comment: How do i skip the 0s?

Comment: _"How do i skip the 0s?"_ Include a `!= 0` in your condition.

Comment: i just figured that out, and realize how dumb my question was :). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        int getLeastOccurredDigit(int number)
        {
            int freqList[10] = { 0 };
            int pNum = (number < 0) ? -number : number;
            while (pNum != 0)
            {
                freqList[(pNum % 10)]++;
                pNum /= 10;
            }
        int MAX_FREQUENCY = (sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT+2)/3;   
    /*(sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT+2)/3 is an upper bound on the number of octal
      digits required for an int, and hence is an upper bound on the number 
   of decimal digits required for an int. by Martin Bonner [in comments]*/
            int small=MAX_FREQUENCY,index=0; 
            for(int i=1;i<10;i++)
            {
                if(small>freqList[i]&&freqList[i]!=0)
                {
                    index=i;
                    small=freqList[i];
                }
            }
            return index;
        }
```

Comment: AH. i understand now. i did the same thing earlier without storing [i] in index like you did to return to main so it always mess up. Thanks

Comment: "int can only be a maximum of 10 digits" - the standard does not guarantee that.  I can remember when `int` would always fit in 5 digits, and a 64-bit `int` (with about 20 digits) is perfectly legal.  `sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT` is an upper bound on the number of value bits in an int.  `(sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT+2)/3`is an upper bound on the number of octal digits required for an int, and hence is an upper bound on the number of decimal digits required for an int.

Answer (score 0):

Since you got answered already, I'll post alternative version, where you are not restricted just by arrays:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

int LeastDigit(const int& num)
{
    std::string snum = std::to_string(num);
    std::map<char, size_t> occur;
    std::pair<char, size_t> result;

    for(auto& x : snum)
        occur[x]++;
    result = *occur.begin();

    for(auto& x : occur)
        if(x.second < result.second)
            result = x;

    return int(result.first-48);
}

int main()
{
    int num = 112233455, result;
    result = LeastDigit(num);
    std::cout << "Your digit: " << result << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

STL makes your life easier.